# Можно ли считать допустимым вопрос про заключение договора на разработку ПО?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика

Можно ли считать [такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1096916/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%9f%d0%9e) допустимым или нет?
С одной стороны он относится к ПО → можно, но ведь он не связан с программированием и системным администрированием. Как быть?

Comment: Можно. Вопросы о лицензиям у нас вроде онтопик, так почему бы и близкому по теме не быть им

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На мой взгляд, вполне является.